# OptaPlanner detailed release notes

Tags: version, optaplanner

Is there somewhere where detailed release notes are located? I am specifically looking for what's in v8.24 and v8.24.1, as I am using 8.23.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [full changelog](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/compare/8.23.0.Final...8.24.1.Final) between any two versions can be found on Github.
We do not publish any written release notes - personally, I think that we should get better at that.

Comment: Thank for the link, but yes it would be useful to have written notes :)